# Laravel 5.8 Authentication plugin not enabled

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a problem with my laravel application:

The error is the following:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2059] Authentication plugin 'mysql_clear_password' cannot be loaded: plugin not enabled (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

How is it possible to enable this plugin without root access to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem now by deleting the whole database and recreating it. -.-

Answer (score 0):

Not without root access, there is a good reason why that would not be enabled, sending passwords as cleartext is not a good idea.  Assuming your hosting in a shared environment then would need to ask the provider if they would be willing to enable it.

Comment: The strange thing is, that my application worked perfectly until a few days ago. Can't that be a wrong configuration in Laravel?

Comment: It is possible, you would need to look at any changes you have made between it working and not.  It could also be an update that the provider has made to the server.